# Как вывести из БД таблицу?

Tags: база-данных, php

```
<html><head><title>key</title></head><body><?phpfunction mysqlcon() {    $db = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","");    mysql_select_db ("baza",$db); }if ($_POST['submit1'] == 'OK' ) {$rez = $_POST['resultat'];$num1 =  $_POST['number1'];$num2 =  $_POST['number2'];$num3 =  $_POST['number3'];$num4 =  $_POST['number4'];$znak =  $_POST['znak'];$znak2 =  $_POST['znak2'];$znak3 =  $_POST['znak3'];if ($znak == 1 && $znak2 == 3 && $znak3 == 5) {    $proverka = $num1 + $num2 + $num3 + $num4;      $proverka2 = (string) $num1 .'+'. $num2 .'+'. $num3 .'+'. $num4;    }if ( $znak == 2 && $znak2 == 4 && $znak3 == 6) {    $proverka = $num1 - $num2 - $num3 - $num4;    $proverka2 = (string) $num1 .'-'. $num2 .'-'. $num3 .'-'. $num4;    }if ($znak == 1 && $znak2 == 3 && $znak3 == 6) {    $proverka = $num1 + $num2 + $num3 - $num4;    $proverka2 = (string) $num1 .'+'. $num2 .'+'. $num3 .'-'. $num4;    }if ($znak == 1 && $znak2 == 4 && $znak3 == 5) {    $proverka = $num1 + $num2 - $num3 + $num4;    $proverka2 = (string) $num1 .'+'. $num2 .'-'. $num3 .'+'. $num4;    }if ($znak == 1 && $znak2 == 4 && $znak3 == 6) {    $proverka = $num1 + $num2 - $num3 - $num4;    $proverka2 = (string) $num1 .'+'. $num2 .'-'. $num3 .'-'. $num4;    }    if ($znak == 2 && $znak2 == 3 && $znak3 == 5) {    $proverka = $num1 - $num2 + $num3 + $num4;    $proverka2 = (string) $num1 .'-'. $num2 .'+'. $num3 .'+'. $num4;    }    if ($znak == 2 && $znak2 == 3 && $znak3 == 6) {    $proverka = $num1 - $num2 + $num3 - $num4;    $proverka2 = (string) $num1 .'-'. $num2 .'+'. $num3 .'-'. $num4;    }    if ($znak == 2 && $znak2 == 4 && $znak3 == 5) {    $proverka = $num1 - $num2 - $num3 + $num4;    $proverka2 = (string) $num1 .'-'. $num2 .'-'. $num3 .'+'. $num4;    }       if ($proverka == $rez) {echo "<div style=\"color:green;\"><h3>$rez - PRAVIL`NO<h3></div>";$resultatik = 'Y';} else {echo "<div style=\"color:red;\"><h3>$rez - NE PRAVIL`NO<h3></div>";$resultatik = 'N';}mysqlcon();$sql = "INSERT INTO`baza`.`mybd` (`id` , `data` , `vopros` , `otvet` , `pravilno` , `resultat` ) VALUES ( NULL ,NOW(),'".$proverka2."','".$rez."','".$proverka."','".$resultatik."');";echo '<pre>'.$sql.'</pre>';if (mysql_query($sql)) {    echo 'SAVED';} else {    echo 'ERROR';}} else {$a=rand(1,20);$b=rand(1,20);$x=rand(1,20);$y=rand(1,20);$c=rand(1,2);$q=rand(3,4);$w=rand(5,6);if ($c == 1) $znak = '+'; if ($c == 2) $znak = '-';if ($q == 3) $znak2 = '+';if ($q == 4) $znak2 = '-';if ($w == 5) $znak3 = '+';if ($w == 6) $znak3 = '-';echo "<h2>$a $znak $b $znak2 $x $znak3 $y= </h2>";?><form action="key.php" method="post"/>Введите результат:<input type="text" name="resultat" /><input type="submit" name="submit1" value="OK"/><input type="hidden" name="number1" value="<?php echo $a; ?>"/><input type="hidden" name="number2" value="<?php echo $b; ?>"/><input type="hidden" name="number3" value="<?php echo $x; ?>"/><input type="hidden" name="number4" value="<?php echo $y; ?>"/><input type="hidden" name="znak" value="<?php echo $c; ?>"/><input type="hidden" name="znak2" value="<?php echo $q; ?>"/><input type="hidden" name="znak3" value="<?php echo $w; ?>"/>    </form></body></html><?php}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

На языке SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM baza
```

или     SELECT id, data, vopros, otvet, pravilno, resultat FROM baza

На PHP+SQL+HTML:

```
<?phpmysqlcon();$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, data, vopros, otvet, pravilno, resultat FROM baza") //Запрос к БД    or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error()); //Обработка запроса и если запрос кривой, сообщаем об этом$result = mysql_fetch_array($result); // фетчим записи таблицы, создаем массив с данными// Красиво выводим на страницуecho <<<HEREDOCИдентификатор: "$id"Дата: "$data"ВОПРОС: "$vopros"ОТВЕТ: "$otvet"Правильно: "$pravilno"Результат: "$resultat"HEREDOC;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

- mysql_query ($queryString,**$connection**);

> Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\key.php on line 95

- переменные, которые присутствуют вставке, в самом начале обявите

  $proverka2=0,$rez=0,$proverka=0,$resultatik=0;

***UPD***Попробуй в таком духе :

```
    <html><head><title>key</title></head><body><?phpextract($_POST); if ( $submit1 =="OK" )  {    if ( ($znak == 1) && ($znak2 == 3) && ($znak3 == 5))         {            $proverka = $number1 + $number2 + $number3 + $number4;              $proverka2 =  $number1 .'+'. $number2 .'+'. $number3 .'+'. $number4;    }     else     if ( ($znak == 2 )&& ($znak2 == 4) && ($znak3 == 6))     {    $proverka = $number1 - $number2 - $number3 - $number4;    $proverka2 = $number1 .'-'. $number2 .'-'. $number3 .'-'. $number4;    }    else     if (($znak == 1) && ($znak2 == 3 )&&( $znak3 == 6))     {    $proverka = $number1 + $number2 + $number3 - $number4;    $proverka2 =  $number1 .'+'. $number2 .'+'. $number3 .'-'. $number4;    }    else    if (($znak == 1) && ($znak2 == 4) && ($znak3 == 5))     {    $proverka = $number1 + $number2 - $number3 + $number4;    $proverka2 = $number1 .'+'. $number2 .'-'. $number3 .'+'. $number4;    }    else    if (($znak == 1) && ($znak2 == 4) && ($znak3 == 6))     {    $proverka = $number1 + $number2 - $number3 - $number4;    $proverka2 =  $number1 .'+'. $number2 .'-'. $number3 .'-'. $number4;    }        else    if (($znak == 2) && ($znak2 == 3 )&& ($znak3 == 5))     {    $proverka = $number1 - $number2 + $number3 + $number4;    $proverka2 = $number1 .'-'. $number2 .'+'. $number3 .'+'. $number4;    }        else    if (($znak == 2) && ($znak2 == 3) && ($znak3 == 6))     {    $proverka = $number1 - $number2 + $number3 - $number4;    $proverka2 =$number1 .'-'. $number2 .'+'. $number3 .'-'. $number4;    }        else    if (($znak == 2) && ($znak2 == 4 )&& ($znak3 == 5))     {    $proverka = $number1 - $number2 - $number3 + $number4;    $proverka2 = $number1 .'-'. $number2 .'-'. $number3 .'+'. $number4;    }  }if ($proverka == $rez) {echo "<div style=\"color:green;\"><h3>$rez - PRAVIL`NO<h3></div>";$resultatik = 'Y';} else {echo "<div style=\"color:red;\"><h3>$rez - NE PRAVIL`NO<h3></div>";$resultatik = 'N';}$db = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());;    mysql_select_db ("baza",$db);$sql = "INSERT INTO`baza`.`mybd` (`id` , `data` , `vopros` , `otvet` , `pravilno` , `resultat` ) VALUES ( NULL ,NOW(),'".$proverka2."','".$rez."','".$proverka."','".$resultatik."');";echo '<pre>'.$sql.'</pre>';$res = mysql_query($sql,$db) or die(mysql_error());if($res)    echo 'SAVED'; else     echo 'ERROR';}
```

Comment: не получаетсяи мне бы как-нибудь с помощью table

Comment: Я пошел за пивом. Без обид... дальше продолжишь, думаю...

Comment: да я в этом деле не понимаю,меньше недели этим занимаюсьнебудет какойто книги посоветовать?